# Using SSIS Catalog with an old (updated) SSIS package. The driver is out of date. Any way to update?

Tags: ssis-2016

We are in the process of upgrading a server from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2016. I've taken a 2008 SSIS project and saved it in SSISDB.  I'm getting a validation error that the driver isn't available.  This is unsurprising since it's a very old driver.  The connection manager in question has an expression that overwrites the connection string with the contents of a variable. I've updated the variable in an Environment, however the validation appears to be happening before the connection manager is updated.

I've checked various places, including the Connection Managers tab of the configuration, a couple of the system tables in SSISDB and the Environment but can't see any way to update the driver or even just tell the package to delay validation.

I know several ways I could fix this if I was willing to edit the packages in the project but I would rather avoid that if possible as I'm going to be doing a fair number of these.

Comment: A connection manager has an Expression on a property. That property is uses a Variable. It's deployed to the SSISDB and there you have a Configuration applied to the Variable to drive run-time behavior. The issue is the package won't pass validation to pick up the run-time values?

Comment: @billinkc You got it.